# Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="identifierId"]"} in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I want to automate download to local and sent report (dashboard data studio) via email, but when I run the code  in data studio , the chrome driver open, show notice "Report cannot be viewed at this time or does not have access" what should I do ? Here is my code :

```
# login to datastudio & refresh the newest data
self.chrome_driver.get(self.url)  
self.chrome_driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys(self.email + u'\ue007')
self.quick_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys(self.password+u'\ue007')
self.quick_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.report_refresh))).click() # refresh report data
time.sleep(15)
# download file to local path
try:
    ActionChains(self.chrome_driver).context_click(self.chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.product_export)).perform()
    self.quick_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.product_download))).click()
    time.sleep(20)
    self.quick_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, self.report_download))).click()
    self.chrome_driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.report_to_pdf).click()
    time.sleep(20)
except AssertionError as error:
    print(error)
    self.chrome_driver.quit()
```

I got error message like:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="identifierId"]"}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no identifyable element with ID "identifierId" in your application. Check again the id attribute of your desired webelement.

Comment: If you are sure the element with that id exist on the page, make sure you have the wait until the element is present before interacting.

Comment: What is the URL `self.url`?

Comment: @Manmohan_singh i cant found wheres the identifierid

Comment: @supputuri i should place time.sleep before line identifierid ?

Comment: `self.url = config.url_a` where the url_a in the config file, example `url_a = 'https://datastudio.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx` @Anwarvic

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with page load.try adding implicit or explicit wait.

1.Apply required wait (implicit or explicit wait)

Implicit wait

```
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

Explicit wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'result-list-entry')]")))
```

Example:

```
self.chrome_driver.implicitly_wait(15)
self.chrome_driver.get(self.url)
self.quick_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "identifierId")))
self.chrome_driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys(self.email + u'\ue007')
self.quick_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys(self.password+u'\ue007')
```

2.Check whether element is a child of iframe element. if so, switch to iframe and try to click

Comment: @ayosuva where i should place the implicit wait ? before line `self.chrome_driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys(self.email + u'\ue007')
` ?

Comment: add it before ```self.chrome_driver.get(self.url)  ```

Comment: its cant work, i got the same error after add `self.chrome_driver.implicitly_wait(15)`

Comment: Can I get the URL?

Comment: example url 'url_a= 'https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/1UgfSeUqUnT2xj58smh3nmyMx1RfeOf8i/page/yvw0'

Comment: Looks like I don't have access. Have you checked whether identified element is present inside iframe or not?

Comment: i should inspect every element and recheck does it present ?

Comment: Can you please have a look http://allselenium.info/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: @Nadyaf Can you please post the screenshot element that you wanted interact?So that i can try it on my own accunt

Comment: i have edit the questions what the element exist @Yosuva

Comment: @Nadyaf I couldn't find element_by_id("identifierId") in your html screenshot. If possible can you please paste you page source into question?